# Entity Framework Core with SQLite SQLCipher and thread-safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, entity-framework, sqlcipher

I want to use

- SQLite with SQLCipher
- Entity Framework Core 3.1
- Multiple Threads that call the Db (thread-safe)

The EF DbContext is not thread-safe natively.
My approach was using a new DbContext for each db call, which is looking like that:

DbProvider

```
public Db GetDbContext()
{
    var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
        DataSource = this.DbLocation,
        Mode = this.DbMode,
        Password = this.dbPassword,
    };
    return new Db(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
}
```

Default Db Call

```
using (var db = this.dbProvider.GetDbContext())
{
     var dataFromDb = db.DbSetXYZ.ToList()
}
```

`this.dbProvider.GetDbContext()` returns a new `DbContext` instance with a new `SqliteConnection`.

DbContext

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    this.sqliteConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
    this.sqliteConnection.Open();
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlite(this.sqliteConnection);
}
```

Without SQLCipher the performance is great. I see no big loading times ~10ms.
With SQLCipher, the performace of `this.sqliteConnection.Open();` changed to **2 seconds**.

**Is there any kind of best practice for this scenario?**

Comment: A DbContext isn't a database connection. It's a client-side, disconnected Unit-of-Work and multi-entity repository. It tracks all changes made on the client side and only opens a connection when `SaveChanges` is called to persist *all* of them in a single transaction. Until then, there's no connection. Discard it, and the changes are gone. It doesn't need to be thread safe and *definitely shouldn't* be recycled for every operation. That breaks its transaction semantics - if you use a different one for every change, how are you going to roll back anything?

Comment: `Multiple Threads that call the Db (thread-safe)` why do you think you need that? That's where the problem starts. What the code shows is definitely a *bad* practice.

Comment: PS - SQLite is a single-user embedded database too, so even though you create the connections manually you still have problems. Even if you use WAL mode, what you read will lag behind writes. SQLite won't block readers until writes get committed, so even though your code won't crash, it will read stale data

Comment: The application is a wpf ui, which loads data from the db into a viewmodel, manipulate it by the user and save it back to the db. If the user do not want to save the changes, the view and the dbcontext get disposed. In the applications are multiple background threads, that polls different data and write them to the db. Yes, I know the issue of outdated data, caused by multiple threads read and write at the same time. That's another reason, why I search a better approach.

Comment: I had the idea to write some kind of dispatcher. It will take all db actions, and enqueue them into a separate db thread, which execute them. In this case, I have only one DbContext (not good) and only one SQLite open (good) command.